# Problem saving to database in custom extension

Tags: database

In an extension that I recently wrote I am having trouble getting the data to save to the database. The foreach and if else statements seem to be working fine, but the "setData" and "Save" functions are not. Is there an error in the code below or is it more likely that I did not set something up correctly in the Model?

```
foreach($data as $set){
                    if (is_null($set[0])){
                        $policies=Mage::getModel('marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies');
                        $policies->setData('policy_title', $set[1]);
                        $policies->setData('policy_details', $set[2]);
                        $policies->setData('partner_id', $partnerid);
                        $policies->save();
                    }
                    else {
                        $collection=Mage::getModel('marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('policy_id',array('eq'=>$set[0]))
                                ->addFieldToFilter('partner_id',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                        if(count($collection)>0){
                            foreach($collection as $data){
                                $data->setData('policy_title', $set[1]);
                                $data->setData('policy_details', $set[2]);
                                $data->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies extension
 * 
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 * 
 * This source file is subject to the MIT License
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * @category       ZeroBars
 * @package        ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies
 * @copyright      Copyright (c) 2014
 * @license        http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies>
            <version>1.1.9</version>
        </ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <marketplacepolicies>
                <class>ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>marketplacepolicies_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </marketplacepolicies>
            <marketplacepolicies_mysql4>
                <class>ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <marketplacepolicies>
                         <table>marketplace_policies</table>
                    </marketplacepolicies>
                </entities>
            </marketplacepolicies_mysql4>

        </models>
        <resources>
            <marketplacepolicies_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </marketplacepolicies_setup>
            <marketplacepolicies_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </marketplacepolicies_write>
            <marketplacepolicies_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </marketplacepolicies_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <marketplacepolicies>
                <class>ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies_Block</class>
            </marketplacepolicies>
        </blocks>
      <helpers>
            <marketplacepolicies>
                <class>ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies_Helper</class>
            </marketplacepolicies>
       </helpers>

    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
             <marketplacepolicies>
                <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies</module>
                        <frontName>marketplacepolicies</frontName>
                    </args>
            </marketplacepolicies>
            <marketplace>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                                <ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies before="Webkul_Marketplace">ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies</ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
            </marketplace>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <marketplacepolicies>
                    <file>zerobars_marketplacepolicies.xml</file>
                </marketplacepolicies>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Contents of MySQL4 file:

```
<?php

class ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies_Model_Mysql4_Marketplacepolicies extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {    
        // Note that the mpshipping_id refers to the key field in your database table.
        $this->_init('marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies', 'policy_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After add table or change your db structure you need to clear cache.

Change

```
Mage::getModel('zerobars_marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies')
```

to

```
Mage::getModel('marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies')
```

Comment: Changed the model call in my file and received the following: 

Fatal error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on a non-object in /home/devzerob/public_html/app/design/frontend/zb-2013/default/template/zerobars_marketplacepolicies/edit_policies.phtml on line 38

I've added my config.xml file in the original post to verify that it is set up correctly.

Comment: Please add your config and module class definition

Comment: Just added and changed all mention of 'zerobars_marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies' to 'marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies' and am ending up with a 500 server error

Comment: ->addFieldToFilter('policy_id',array('eq'=>$set[0])) is in the controller.

I missed the ('zerobars_marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies') mentions in the collection files. I changed them to ('marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies') and now the page is loading again, but the policies are still not saving

Comment: This is line 38 in edit policies:
$policiescollection=Mage::getModel('marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('partner_id',array('eq'=>$partnerId));

Comment: Add this code above `$policie=Mage::getModel('marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies')->load([put a valid id here]); echo $policie->getId();` do you get an error?

Comment: Also change this `if(count($collection)>0){` to `if($collection)->getSize())`

Comment: The output for that code is "1" which is the valid ID used.

Comment: Did you create ZeroBars/Marketplacepolicies/Model/Mysql4/Marketplacepolicies/Collection.php?

Comment: Yes, the collection file is created. The getModel call is returning the correct information now and the page is loading, but the updated information is not saving to the database. When I make changes and click save the page reloads without the new data. Getting 200 OK response to the save function in my Network panel.

Comment: Did you clear all your cache in admin

Comment: Yes just cleared cache with the same result. The policies will not save.

Comment: Try to manually save something `$policie=Mage::getModel('marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies')->load([put a valid id here]); print_r($policie->getData()); $policie->set[Fieldname]()->save(); print_r($policie->getData());`

Comment: Just added this to edit_policies.phtml:

$policie=Mage::getModel('marketplacepolicies/marketplacepolicies')->load(1); 
  print_r($policie->getData()); 
  $policie->setData('policy_title', 'manual sample');
  $policie->setData('policy_details', 'manually changed');
  $policie->setData('partner_id', 6);
  $policie->save();
  print_r($policie->getData());
Result:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies_Model_Mysql4_Marketplacepolicies::saveInSetIncluding() in /home/devzerob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute.php on line 211

Comment: I should note the first call to getData worked correctly, but the second resulted in the error.

Comment: add the content of this file to your question `ZeroBars_Marketplacepolicies_Model_Mysql4_Marketplacepolicies`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17184/discussion-between-r-s-and-kray).